# Paste value from a Userform to a Excel Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to Paste values from an Excel Userform to a sheet. The values can be pasted into diffrent sheets depending on what you put inside of the Userform.

I have come this far:

```
Private Sub Lagginarenda_Click()
Sheets("KategoriComboBox").Range("B2").Value = TextBoxFragestallare.Value
End Sub
```

The **KategoriComboBox** is a Userform Dropdown list in which you can choose a name in. The same values that contains in that list have a similar Excel sheet.

The **TextBoxFragestallare** is a TextBox in which you can write in a value. This Value I want to paste inside of Cell B2 in a sheet that you also choose inside of the userform.

The Code wont work because it says "Index out of bound- Runtime error '9'"

---

I have managed to come this far:

```
Private Sub Lagginarende_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long

'Aktiverar sheet
Sheets("Byggkonstruktion").Activate

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Överför information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBoxLopnummer.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TextBoxFragestallare.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = TextBoxMottagare.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = TextBoxDatum.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = TextBoxFraga.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = TextBoxSvar.Value
If KanBesvaraFraganJa.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = KanBesvaraFraganJa.Caption Else Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = KanBesvaraFraganNej.Caption

Unload Me
End Sub
```

The only issue I have now is how can I instead of using **Sheets("Byggkonstruktion").Activate** use the value in a drop-down list that is in the userform?

Comment: Is KategoriComboBox a dropdown list or a Sheet? By dropdown list you mean a ComboBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Sub` below probably works for you.
You should suitably qualify `Range`s, and avoid using `Select` or `Activate` unless they are strictly needed.

Note that you should: 1) populate your `ComboBox` prior to using it, 2) make sure that the selected value in the `ComboBox` is what you want, so you can use `KategoriComboBox.Value`, 3) make sure that there exists the worksheet you are trying to use in the `ActiveWorkbook`, or choose it suitably.

```
Private Sub Lagginarende_Click()
    Dim emptyRow As Long

    'Aktiverar sheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(KategoriComboBox.Value)
    'Sheets("Byggkonstruktion").Activate

    'Determine emptyRow
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A:A")) + 1
    'emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

    'Överför information
    ws.Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBoxLopnummer.Value
    ws.Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TextBoxFragestallare.Value
    ws.Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = TextBoxMottagare.Value
    ws.Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = TextBoxDatum.Value
    ws.Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = TextBoxFraga.Value
    ws.Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = TextBoxSvar.Value
    If KanBesvaraFraganJa.Value = True Then ws.Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = KanBesvaraFraganJa.Caption Else ws.Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = KanBesvaraFraganNej.Caption

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Sancho, Sorry for the late response. I have changed my code into yours since it is working good now. One thing, The only thing i changed with my previous and yours is the: ` 
'Aktiverar sheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(KategoriComboBox.Value)
    'Sheets("Byggkonstruktion").Activate

    'Determine emptyRow
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A:A")) + 1
    'emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1`

Could you please explain the difference again why this is a better solution? Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I still need this snippet to manage to run your code: `Private Sub KategoriComboBox_Change()
   
   Sheets(KategoriComboBox.Text).Activate
  
End Sub`

Comment: @Joneskvist - *Why this is a better solution?* It qualifies `Range`s and avoids unnecessary use of `Select`. *I still need this snippet...* You shouldn't. Please check you are strictly paying attention to the 3 steps listed. You might use the debugger, watches, and the immediate window to see what is going on.

Comment: I have checked the 3 steps and they are correct. Unfortunately I do now know how to use the Debugger or the other tools.

Comment: @Joneskvist - Weighing the case, I think you would be ok (not optimal) with leaving it here. Unless you want to [learn a little about the Excel VBA debugger](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+excel+vba+debugger)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to let the user select a certain sheet name through a dropdown control and then paste the text they entered in this sheet in cell 'B2'.

So your setup might look something like this:
[image: Demo application for pasting on selected sheet]

[image: Enter text]

[image: Text is pasted on selected sheet]

Here is how you can achieve this:
(Suppose you have a ComboBox named cbxSheet, a TextBox named txbText and a CommandButton named btnCopyTextToSelectedSheet in a UserForm)

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim wksCurrentSheet As Worksheet

    'Add all available sheet names to dropdown box
    For Each wksCurrentSheet In Worksheets
        cbxSheet.AddItem wksCurrentSheet.Name
    Next wksCurrentSheet

End Sub

Private Sub btnCopyTextToSelectedSheet_Click()

    Dim strText As String
    Dim strSheetName As String
    Dim wksDestination As Worksheet

    'Read sheet name from dropdown box
    strSheetName = cbxSheet.Value

    'Try to get sheet with the defined name
    Set wksDestination = Worksheets(strSheetName)
    'If there is no sheet with this name you will receive
    'an 'Index out of bound' (9) runtime error

    'Get text from textbox
    strText = txbText.Text

    'Write to cell in destination worksheet
    wksDestination.Activate     'Not needed, just to let the user see
                            'that the copying really happens :)
    wksDestination.Range("B2").Value = strText

    'Unload form (makes sure the UserForm_Initialize sub is called on
    '             each use of the form)
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

I uploaded the sample here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40951326/SheetSelectionExample.xlsm

Hope this gives you an idea on how to achieve what you want!

Comment: Hi, I only want to activate the sheet that is choosen in the Drop-down menu that is in the UserForm. This wont work `Sheets(KategoriComboBox.Value).Activate`for some strange reason. Do you have any clue? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Joneskvist - "This wont work": Please describe exactly and in detail what happens.

Comment: Hi, I managed to fix it now, I did like this :

`Private Sub KategoriComboBox_Change()
   
   Sheets(KategoriComboBox.Text).Activate
  
End Sub`

I only needed to create a new private sub and it activates the sheet chosen in the ComboBox :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you just want:

```
Private Sub Lagginarenda_Click()
Sheets(KategoriComboBox.Value).Range("B2").Value = TextBoxFragestallare.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi how come In can't use this : `Sheets(KategoriComboBox.Value).Activate`?

Answer (score 0):

The Answer to my question is the following:

```
Private Sub KategoriComboBox_Change()

   Sheets(KategoriComboBox.Text).Activate

End Sub
```

What it does it that it activates the sheet that has the same name as the one you choose in the Combobox.

Comment: Great that it works! The question about why what you were doing before did not work is buried then. As per your answer, you might have been missing point 3 in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27704110/2707864). Still note that you should only use `Activate` when strictly needed. Your approach with `Activate` might be not the best, but still working.

Comment: I see, Do you recommend any other approach beside doing what I did? I tried your solution but it did not paste the values in the sheet that I wanted. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes. I do recommend following my suggestions. If you tried the code I posted, and the values were actually pasted but in a different worksheet, then you are probably missing point 2 (or there may be another `ActiveWorkbook` with a worksheet having the same name; unlikely?). Again, unless you specifically need Activating the target worksheet for other reasons than pasting values.